# Google App script function returned null instead of returned value when recalled

Tags: function, google-apps-script, logging

i would like to ask this question on GOOGLE APP SCRIPT:

i have this script :

```
let jmlTUPDNet; 


function JmlhTransaksi (a,b) {
  let DataBruto = UserPageSheet.getRange(12,b,UserPageSheet.getLastRow(),1).getValues();

  // Logger.log(DataBruto)

  let DataNetto = DataBruto.filter(
    innerArray => innerArray.join("") !== "" 
);

// console.log(DataNetto);

 a = DataNetto.length

 Logger.log(a)

 return a = DataNetto.length

}  

JmlhTransaksi(jmlTUPDNet,1)

Logger.log(jmlTUPDNet)
```

the thing is, when i log the "jmlTUPDNet" within the function, it returns "1", but when i log it outside the function (the last Logger.log) it return null.

is there something im missing there?

thanks in advance

i wish the logger log outside the function  is also return "1", so i can use it on another function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Except for objects or arrays, parameters passed to function are by value, not by reference.  You are passing an undefined value `jmlTUPDNet` to `JmlhTransaksi` .  I believe what you want to do is

```
let  jmlTUPDNet = JmlhTransaksi(1);
```

and

```
function JmlhTransaksi(b) {
  .......
  let a = DataNetto.length;
  return a;
}
```